# Select columns that do not appear with another column value

Tags: mysql

I have a table with two columns `UID` and `GID` where there is a many-to-one GID-UID relationship (i.e. each UID can appear in many rows with different GIDs).

If I want to get all UIDs that have a certain GID, that's easy

```
SELECT
  UID
FROM
  MyTable
WHERE
  GID = x
```

But what if I want all UIDs that do *not* have a certain GID? I came up with this:

```
SELECT
  UID
FROM
  (SELECT
    UID, MAX(GID = x) AS has_gid
  FROM
    MyTable
  GROUP BY
    UID
  ) AS subq
WHERE
  has_gid = 0
```

I think that works, but it seems like such a hack for such a simple sounding problem. Is there some obvious or more efficient way to do this that I'm missing?

Comment: Usually a way to find *do not have* rows is to make `OUTER JOIN` and filter for `IS NULL`.

Comment: `what if I want all UIDs that do not have a certain GID` then why not simply filter them out like `select UID from mytable WHERE GID NOT IN (x,y,z,w,...)`

Comment: In my case there are over a hundred GID values and more are added regularly. It would seem more proper to have the query only dependent on the one value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sub-query like this:

```
SELECT
  UID
FROM
  MyTable
WHERE
  UID 
   NOT IN
   (SELECT
     distinct t.UID
    FROM
      MyTable t
    WHERE
      GID = uid_to_exclude)
```

But this query may runs more fast:

```
SELECT
  t1.UID
FROM
  MyTable t1 
  LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT
     DISTINCT t.UID as UID2
    FROM
      MyTable t
    WHERE
      t.GID = uid_to_exclude) as t2 on t1.uid = t2.uid 

WHERE t2.UID2 IS NULL
```

Comment: It isn't obvious to me which method would be more efficient. Both involve a subquery and I can imagine that `IN` being very expensive.

Comment: I added a new query that runs more fast.

Comment: This query is much slower than the one in my question. Mine take about a minute to select 5 million UIDs out of 150 million (UID,GID) pairs. Yours I had to kill after running for about 20 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to write such a query, i.e. using an outer join and checking selecting the null values, but I think the most readable and also efficient query is to use the `NOT EXISTS` sql function

```
SELECT UID 
  FROM MYTABLE
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
      FROM MYTABLE T1
     WHERE T1.UID = MYTABLE.UID
       AND T1.GID = X
 )
```

Comment: I couldn't get this query to work. It keeps return all UIDs, not just those without the GID.

Comment: I think the query works. I have created a fiddle to demonstrate this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc282b/8
The result will contain the values `1` and `2` since there are no tuples `(1,4)` and `(2,4)`